# Irregular key mapping?

Tags: 10.04, keyboard

Any better title is welcome. All of a sudden when I press:

- <kbd>d</kbd> - I either see d typed in or I get a print screen window
- <kbd>e</kbd> - I either see e typed or I see volume bar rise
- <kbd>c</kbd> - I either see c typed or I have many different effects (depends on context)

So far I'm unable to tell what is the "trigger" or "toggle" for this peculiarity.

I'm frankly at a loss what to investigate. Few findings:
- while this first manifested in a browser (FF + Vimperator) this is NOT browser limited
- GVim, terminal even tty (I switched to it) can have that
- In tty <kbd>d</kbd> becomes `\;` and <kbd>c</kbd> becomes `^[[5~b` and presses Enter.
- in `kern.log` I see no entries when tailing when I press <kbd>d</kbd> even when I see volume bar increasing upon keypress 
- I see no strange shortcuts when I open `Keyboard Shortcuts` window

Any clues? I had not run any updates recently, nor have I installed something. This interrupts my work to the point I had to borrow someone else's laptop to type this.

### **UPDATE**

Visa1:

- <kbd>3</kbd> - deletes first character in line and puts cursor there
- <kbd>#</kbd> - inserts last cut or highlighted (I'm unsure here) thing

These have been tested only in terminal and tty and login shell.

Another keyboard - currently none at hand that I can plug in.

@Mordoc
FN key inputs:

I don't think it's jammed key. Fn key works as expected except for volume. Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> doesn't give me e, though I had few times earlier, before posting this question where I had "toggled" this with function key. This however is not consistent.

Normal volume keys were on <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> and they do not work now. Mute key works as usual. So, it rather isn't the case for jammed key but it still found us something new.

### 2nd UPDATE

Problem "solved" itself equally suddenly as it had manifested.** Leaving this open for a week or so. Vasa1 - your comments were closest to the cause I think, so feel free to post them as an answer, along with "another keyboard" suggestion.

### 3rd UPDATE - root cause identified, problem solved

After a year the problem reappeared and what I noticed further is:

1. it appeared more often when laptop was in unbalanced position
2. it often disappeared when I pressed region next to touchpad

Took the laptop to the service and voila - keyboard was faulty. On new keyboard problem does not occur. Vasa1, right on the money.

Comment: What about # and 3? And have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: I would be curious if a fn key press would do the same actions. For example on my laptop some of those keys are mapped to functions while holding down the fn key. Could it be that a key is stuck like the fn or ctrl key?

Comment: @vasa1 you have some hidden knowledge it seems! # and 3 also have hidden behaviour -will update the question with results!

Comment: No special powers ;) It's just that c, d,e, 3 and maybe F2 get affected because they're in the same diagonal line. A friend had a dodgy keyboard with something similar.

Comment: I think you should try to eliminate the possibility that it's a faulty keyboard.

Comment: @vasa1 - I cannot. I wanted to, but problem "solved" itself and all keys work as designed now. :O I guess the question can be closed? :/ I honestly don't know what to make of it. Temporary glitch? Some breadcrumbs that slipped through and caused it? I'll leave this open for a time. If this won't appear a second time, I'd like that you post your comments as an answer and I'll accept it. That seems the closest to actual cause. Once again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @LIttleAncientForestKami, instead of closing, you could just delete it yourself. Keeps things tidier that way.

Comment: @ChrisWilson I kinda concur. But, if the others don't mind, I'd love to keep this here for some time. I distrust [Heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), and this certainly is one.

Comment: @LIttleAncientForestKami, fair enough :)